# Extended raid 5 is not expanding

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ubuntu-14.04, raid5, hp-smart-array

I have a D2700 with 25 1Tb disks with a P421 raid card in a dl360p gen8 HP server.

It was raided as two raid 5 with 2 spare each. I decided to make one raid 5 out of them, deleted one raid and added the disk to the other.

Now weeks later looking at it with hpssacli (new to me) they look fine, all 25 disks show OK, the raid shows OK, but I still only have 11.8 TB, it should show around 23 TB..?

This is what "sudo hpssacli ctrl all show config" gives me:

```
Smart Array P421 in Slot 1                (sn: XXX)

array A (SAS, Unused Space: 8974754  MB)


logicaldrive 1 (11.8 TB, RAID 5, OK)

physicaldrive 2E:1:1 (port 2E:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:2 (port 2E:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:3 (port 2E:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:4 (port 2E:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:5 (port 2E:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:6 (port 2E:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:7 (port 2E:box 1:bay 7, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:8 (port 2E:box 1:bay 8, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:9 (port 2E:box 1:bay 9, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:10 (port 2E:box 1:bay 10, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:11 (port 2E:box 1:bay 11, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:12 (port 2E:box 1:bay 12, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:13 (port 2E:box 1:bay 13, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:14 (port 2E:box 1:bay 14, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:17 (port 2E:box 1:bay 17, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:18 (port 2E:box 1:bay 18, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:19 (port 2E:box 1:bay 19, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:20 (port 2E:box 1:bay 20, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:21 (port 2E:box 1:bay 21, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:22 (port 2E:box 1:bay 22, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:23 (port 2E:box 1:bay 23, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:24 (port 2E:box 1:bay 24, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:25 (port 2E:box 1:bay 25, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
physicaldrive 2E:1:15 (port 2E:box 1:bay 15, SAS, 1 TB, OK, spare)
physicaldrive 2E:1:16 (port 2E:box 1:bay 16, SAS, 1 TB, OK, spare)

Enclosure SEP (Vendor ID HP, Model D2700 SAS AJ941A) 378  (WWID: XXX, Port: 2E, Box: 1)

Expander 379  (WWID: XXX, Port: 2E, Box: 1)

SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model SRCv8x6G) 380  (WWID: XXX)
```

Comment: While you are at it and likely have no data on the disks anyway: **Don't use RAID5**. Take RAID10, RAID6/60, but not RAID5. The likelihood of a failed rebuild due to an URE or another drive failure is just too high with an array of such size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit nuts... That's too many disks for a RAID5. It's offset by the fact that you have two hot-spare drives, *but damn!!*

However, you've already expanded the underlying Array, but not the Logical Drive. Remember, the "Array" is the physical grouping of disks. The "Logical Drive" is what you assign RAID level to. You can have multiple Logical Drives within an Array.

> array A (SAS, Unused Space: 8974754  MB)

That's your unused space, so you can create another Logical Drive out of the free space, or expand `logicaldrive 1`.

`ctrl slot=1 ld 1 modify size=?` or `ctrl slot=1 ld 1 modify size=max`

```
<target> modify [size=#|min|max|maxmbr|?] [forced]
   Extends the logical drive to the specified size. The implied units are MB.
   max will extend the logical drive to its maximum size. maxmbr will extend to
   the maximum size the master partition table allows. The target can be any
   valid logical drive.
```

Comment: logicaldrive 1 (20.0 TB, RAID 5, OK)

Comment: @user1506602 Good deal!

Comment: I took the advice and changed it to raid 6 with 2 spare, it seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Unused Space: 8974754  MB - that 8.55TB. There's your missing space.

You should be able to expand it with `hpacucli` command (`modify size=max` parameter).